# Adding a text field for string input in Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, sql

I would like to run a query that takes a textfield as an input. I know it works fine with `int` [like so](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag):

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

...

WHERE 
    Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
```

But how can I do for text input? Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Location nvarchar (35) = ##Location##

select distinct top 10 Users.Id,Users.DisplayName,sum(Post.Score) as score
  from Users,Posts Questions,Posts Post,PostTags
  where Users.Location=@Location
```

This gives me this error:

> [image]

Ideas?

Also, how coud I add an input field for something like a comma delimited list like so:

```
DECLARE @Tags nvarchar (35) = '##Tags##'

    and PostTags.TagId in
      (select Id from Tags where TagName in
        (@Tags))
```

Ideally I'd like to add stuff like this in the tags.

```
objective-c, iOS
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the string field in string delimiters so it is an acceptable string literal.

```
DECLARE @Location nvarchar (35) = '##Location##'
```

SEDE is not clever enough to add those itself, instead of a direct substitution (it doesn't *know* it is a `varchar`/`nvarchar`) - numeric literals don't have that limitation.

---

As for your `##tags##` variable - that's not how `IN` clauses work in SQL. You can't give a `varchar` with commas to an `IN` and expect that to work - think about the actual SQL and what you need to do in order to translate that to a "variable":

```
select Id from Tags where TagName in ('tag1', 'tag2')
```

You would need to have `##tags##` be replaced exactly with `'tag1', 'tag2'` - not be put into a *single* `varchar` variable - that won't work.

So:

```
select Id from Tags where TagName in (##tags##)
```

And you would need to use `'tag1', 'tag2'` (etc) as replacement.

Comment: thanks! i'll grant the upvote as soon as the timer is up.. in the meantime please see my update

Comment: *(it doesn't know it is a varchar/nvarchar)* that is true but you can tell SEDE you meant the parameter to be a string by adding the type like so: `DECLARE @Location nvarchar (35) = ##Location:string##`. Notice that the type need to be a .Net type, not a SQL type. [Demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485906?Location=test)